# Do not log event id 4688 – A new process has been created

Tags: process, group-policy, event-log, gpedit

Using Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) or Local Security Policy (secpol.msc) Security Settings -> Audit Policy -> Audit Process Tracking or Advanced Audit Policy Configuration -> System Audit Policy -> Detailed Tracking -> Disabled.

Even issuing

```
auditpol /clear
auditpol /get /category:*
```

shows Process creation: no auditing

Still have those event id 4688 in Security Log.

Windows 10

Comment: Did you restart?

Comment: sure i did restart

Comment: Check this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/component-updates/command-line-process-auditing#to-ensure-that-advanced-audit-policy-configuration-settings-are-not-overwritten

Comment: I tried "Audit: Force audit policy subcategory settings (Windows Vista or later) to override audit policy category settings" but I still get the ten or so entries every time I restart